# Pivot Tables Excel

Tags: excel

I have a question about using pivot tables in Excel.  I have multiple fields listed in the rows section; in the table, one field is grouped by the other.  By default, all of the rows in my pivot table are expanded.  However, I would like to make all of the rows compressed by default.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but could it be so easy to just collapse the fields, and then save? Next time you open, the fields should be collapsed.